# Codeception acceptance check if js function is called

Tags: php, codeception, acceptance-testing

i'm trying to create a `php` test to check if a specific `ajax` is executed, but i can't find anything that can help me.

I'm fine even if i can check if the method, whom triggers the `ajax request`, is called (but i think is not possibile to `mock` js functions with `codeception`).

A little example to explain better:

let's assume i have my online page: `http://example.com` with the following js

```
var log = {
    execute: function(){
        // AJAX CALL HERE
    }
};

log.execute();
```

With the test i would like to know if `log.execute()` is executed, so in codeception i can do something like:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);

// Opening page
$I->amOnUrl('http://example.com');

// Checking if log is invoked
$I->wantTo('Check if log is invoked');

// Something to understand if a method is executed
$I->???('log.execute()');
```

Otherwise, i'm fine if there is a method to take the browser network activity and then regex it (do not suggest proxy, don't wanna go there).

I'm open to any kind of solutions, even to use a different testing system (with php)

Edit: i forgot to say that i'm using `selenium` with `chromeDrivers`

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can use `$I->executeJS('Javascript code');` to execute Javascript code. However to check if a code execute, there are a number of ways. One way is to check for side effects (.i.e. DOM changes, Resource changes). Another way is to check return value.

Comment: the problem is, i don't have any DOM changes nor returns, is just an api call that returns nothing, i'm trying to inject via js a watcher for any xhr request